# Wrong output- trying for if the number is Armstrong

Tags: c++

I am new to coding and just starting with the c++ language, here I am trying to find the number given as input if it is Armstrong or not.

> An Armstrong number of three digits is an integer such that the sum of the cubes of its digits is equal to the number itself. For example, 153 is an Armstrong number since 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 153.

But even if I give not an armstrong number, it still prints that number is armstrong.

Below is my code.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool ifarmstrong(int n, int p) {
  int sum = 0;
  int num = n;
  while(num>0){
    num=num%10;
    sum=sum+pow(num,p);
  }
  if(sum==n){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
int main() {
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  int i, p = 0;
  for (i = 0; n > 0; i++) {
    n = n / 10;
  }
  cout << i<<endl;
  if (ifarmstrong(n, i)) {
    cout << "Yes it is armstorng" << endl;
  } else {
    cout << "No it is not" << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

A solution to my problem and explantation to what's wrong

Comment: `if(sum==n){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }` You can make it shorter `return sum == n;`

Comment: Side note: You are better off multiplying out integers than using `pow`. Reasons: `pow` performs floating point arithmetic and often produces results that are within a tolerable level of precision suitable to floating point numbers, but are not always exact. Converting these tolerable results back to an exact value like an integer often results in getting the wrong answer. Plus `pow` is designed to handle the really nasty stuff like e to the power of pi and are overkill when computing exponents of integers.

Comment: Here is the statement that decides whether or not the number is Armstrong: `if(sum==n){ return true; }else{ return false; }`. A natural question to ask is what are the values of `sum` and `n` at this point? *Hint: `std::cout << "sum is " << sum << " and n is " << n << "\n";`* You might end up running your code multiple times when debugging, so make it easier on yourself: `int n = 152;` instead of `int n; cin >> n;`.

Answer (score 2):

This code

```
for (i = 0; n > 0; i++) {
    n = n / 10;
}
```

will set `n` to zero after the loop has executed. But here

```
if (ifarmstrong(n, i)) {
```

you use `n` as if it still had the original value.

Additionally you have a error in your `ifarmstrong` function, this code

```
while(num>0){
    num=num%10;
    sum=sum+pow(num,p);
}
```

result in `num` being zero from the second iteration onwards. Presumably you meant to write this

```
while(num>0){
    sum=sum+pow(num%10,p);
    num=num/10;
}
```

Finally using `pow` on integers is unreliable. Because it's a floating point function and it (presumably) uses logarithms to do it's calculations, it may not return the exact integer result that you are expecting. It's better to use integers if you are doing exact integer calculations.

All these issues (and maybe more) will very quickly be discovered by using a *debugger*. much better than staring at code and scratching your head.